# Joining massive CTE tables (13,000,000 rows+) performance problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

We have a production database that manages personnel booking at 100s of branches for years in advance with minute level accuracy.

Part of this system are reports that highlight gaps, i.e. compare branch opening hours and staff bookings to see if any branches are open with nobody booked.

It also checks for overlaps, double bookings etc all at the same time, basically minute level accuracy is required.

The way we're doing this is to expand the start and end times of openings hours and bookings into minutes with an integer tally table:

```
--===== Create and populate the Tally table on the fly
 SELECT TOP 16777216
        IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS N
   INTO dbo.Tally
   FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
        Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2,
        Master.dbo.SysColumns sc3

--===== Add a Primary Key to maximize performance
  ALTER TABLE dbo.Tally
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Tally_N 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (N) WITH FILLFACTOR = 100
```

We utilise this static indexed tally table to expand opening hours and bookings as follows:

```
SELECT   [BranchID] ,
        [DayOfWeek] ,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, N - 1, StartTime)
FROM     OpeningHours
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tally ON tally.N BETWEEN 0
                                         AND     DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OpeningHours.StartTime, OpeningHours.EndTime) + 1
```

The problem is, once we have the 13,000,000 "open minutes" and the "booked minutes" we then need to join the results to see what's covered:

```
SELECT   OpenDatesAndMinutes.[Date] ,
                                OpenDatesAndMinutes.[Time] ,
                                OpenDatesAndMinutes.[BranchID] ,
                                ISNULL(BookedMinutes.BookingCount, 0) AS BookingCount
                       FROM     OpenDatesAndMinutes
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN BookedMinutes ON OpenDatesAndMinutes.BranchID = BookedMinutes.BranchID
                                                                 AND OpenDatesAndMinutes.[Date] = BookedMinutes.[Date]
                                                                 AND OpenDatesAndMinutes.[Time] = BookedMinutes.[Time]
```

As you can imagine, joining on the branch, date & time with 13,000,000 rows all stored in CTE tables takes AGES - running it for a week isnt too bad, about 10 seconds but if we run it for 6 months (13,000,000 minutes) bloats to 25 minutes+

Once we have joined the open minutes to the booked minutes we then group the data on islands and present to the user:

```
CrossTabPrep ( [Date], [Time], [BranchID], [BookingCount], [Grp] )
  AS ( SELECT   [Date] ,
                [Time] ,
                [BranchID] ,
                [BookingCount] ,
                DATEPART(HOUR, Time) * 60 + DATEPART(MINUTE, Time) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [BranchID], Date, [BookingCount] ORDER BY Time ) AS [Grp]
       FROM     PreRender
     ),
FinalRender ( [BranchID], [Date], [Start Time], [End Time], [Duration], [EntryCount], [EntryColour] )
  AS ( SELECT   [BranchID] ,
                [Date] ,
                MIN([Time]) AS [Start Time] ,
                MAX([Time]) AS [End Time] ,
                ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN([Time]), MAX([Time])), 0) AS Duration ,
                [BookingCount] AS EntryCount ,
                CASE WHEN [BookingCount] = 0 THEN 'Red'
                     WHEN [BookingCount] = 1 THEN 'Green'
                     ELSE 'Yellow'
                END AS EntryColour
       FROM     CrossTabPrep
       GROUP BY [BranchID] ,
                [Date] ,
                [BookingCount] ,
                [Grp]
     )
```

Quite simply, is my method efficient? is there any way i can improve on this method whilst retaining minute level accuracy? When dealing with massive CTE tables such as this, would there be any benefit in dumping this data to indexed temp tables & joining them instead?

Another thing I was considering is replacing the DATE & TIME(0) data types that the big join uses, would is be more efficient if I cast these to integers?

Here is the Full CTE in case that helps:

```
WITH    OpeningHours ( [BranchID], [DayOfWeek], [StartTime], [EndTime] )
          AS ( SELECT   BranchID ,
                        DayOfWeek ,
                        CONVERT(TIME(0), AM_open) ,
                        CONVERT(TIME(0), AM_close)
               FROM     db_BranchDetails.dbo.tbl_ShopOpeningTimes (NOLOCK)
                        INNER JOIN @tbl_Days Filter_Days ON db_BranchDetails.dbo.tbl_ShopOpeningTimes.DayOfWeek = Filter_Days.DayNumber
               WHERE    CONVERT(TIME(0), AM_open) <> CONVERT(TIME(0), '00:00:00')
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   BranchID ,
                        DayOfWeek ,
                        CONVERT(TIME(0), PM_open) ,
                        CONVERT(TIME(0), PM_close)
               FROM     db_BranchDetails.dbo.tbl_ShopOpeningTimes (NOLOCK)
                        INNER JOIN @tbl_Days Filter_Days ON db_BranchDetails.dbo.tbl_ShopOpeningTimes.DayOfWeek = Filter_Days.DayNumber
               WHERE    CONVERT(TIME(0), PM_open) <> CONVERT(TIME(0), '00:00:00')
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   BranchID ,
                        DayOfWeek ,
                        CONVERT(TIME(0), EVE_open) ,
                        CONVERT(TIME(0), EVE_close)
               FROM     db_BranchDetails.dbo.tbl_ShopOpeningTimes (NOLOCK)
                        INNER JOIN @tbl_Days Filter_Days ON db_BranchDetails.dbo.tbl_ShopOpeningTimes.DayOfWeek = Filter_Days.DayNumber
               WHERE    CONVERT(TIME(0), EVE_open) <> CONVERT(TIME(0), '00:00:00')
             ),
        DateRange ( [Date], [DayOfWeek] )
          AS ( SELECT   CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartDate)) ,
                        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartDate))
               FROM     tally (NOLOCK)
               WHERE    N <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1
             ),
        OpenMinutes ( [BranchID], [DayOfWeek], [Time] )
          AS ( SELECT   [BranchID] ,
                        [DayOfWeek] ,
                        DATEADD(MINUTE, N - 1, StartTime)
               FROM     OpeningHours
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN tally ON tally.N BETWEEN 0
                                                         AND     DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OpeningHours.StartTime, OpeningHours.EndTime) + 1
             ),
        OpenDatesAndMinutes ( [Date], [Time], [BranchID] )
          AS ( SELECT   DateRange.[Date] ,
                        OpenMinutes.[Time] ,
                        OpenMinutes.BranchID
               FROM     DateRange
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN OpenMinutes ON DateRange.DayOfWeek = OpenMinutes.DayOfWeek
               WHERE    OpenMinutes.BranchID IS NOT NULL
             ),
        WhiteListEmployees ( [DET_NUMBERA] )
          AS ( SELECT   DET_NUMBERA
               FROM     [dbo].[tbl_ChrisCache_WhiteList]
               WHERE    [TimeSheetV2_SecurityContext] = @TimeSheetV2_SecurityContext
             ),
        BookedMinutesByRole ( [Date], [Time], [BranchID], BookingCount )
          AS ( SELECT   [BookingDate] ,
                        DATEADD(MINUTE, N - 1, StartTime) ,
                        BranchID ,
                        COUNT(BookingID) AS Bookings
               FROM     tbl_Booking (NOLOCK)
                        INNER JOIN tbl_BookingReason  (NOLOCK) ON dbo.tbl_BookingReason.ReasonID = dbo.tbl_Booking.ReasonID
                        INNER JOIN tbl_ChrisCache  (NOLOCK) ON dbo.tbl_Booking.DET_NUMBERA = dbo.tbl_ChrisCache.DET_NUMBERA
                        INNER JOIN @ValidPosCodes AS Filter_PostCodes ON dbo.tbl_ChrisCache.POS_NUMBERA = Filter_PostCodes.POSCODE
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN tally (NOLOCK) ON tally.N BETWEEN 0
                                                                  AND     DATEDIFF(MINUTE, tbl_Booking.StartTime, tbl_Booking.EndTime) + 1
               WHERE    ( Void = 0 )
                        AND tbl_BookingReason.CoverRequired = 0 --#### Only use bookings that dont require cover
                        AND tbl_booking.BranchID <> '023'   --#### Branch 23 will always have messy data
                        AND ( dbo.tbl_Booking.BookingDate BETWEEN @StartDate
                                                          AND     @EndDate )
               GROUP BY [BookingDate] ,
                        BranchID ,
                        DATEADD(MINUTE, N - 1, StartTime)
             ),
        BookedMinutesByWhiteList ( [Date], [Time], [BranchID], BookingCount )
          AS ( SELECT   [BookingDate] ,
                        DATEADD(MINUTE, N - 1, StartTime) ,
                        BranchID ,
                        COUNT(BookingID) AS Bookings
               FROM     tbl_Booking(NOLOCK)
                        INNER JOIN tbl_BookingReason (NOLOCK) ON dbo.tbl_BookingReason.ReasonID = dbo.tbl_Booking.ReasonID
                        INNER JOIN tbl_ChrisCache (NOLOCK) ON dbo.tbl_Booking.DET_NUMBERA = dbo.tbl_ChrisCache.DET_NUMBERA
                        INNER JOIN WhiteListEmployees Filter_WhiteList ON dbo.tbl_Booking.DET_NUMBERA = Filter_WhiteList.DET_NUMBERA
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN tally (NOLOCK) ON tally.N BETWEEN 0
                                                                  AND     DATEDIFF(MINUTE, tbl_Booking.StartTime, tbl_Booking.EndTime) + 1
               WHERE    ( Void = 0 )
                        AND tbl_BookingReason.CoverRequired = 0 --#### Only use bookings that dont require cover
                        AND tbl_booking.BranchID <> '023'   --#### Branch 23 will always have messy data
                        AND ( dbo.tbl_Booking.BookingDate BETWEEN @StartDate
                                                          AND     @EndDate )
               GROUP BY [BookingDate] ,
                        BranchID ,
                        DATEADD(MINUTE, N - 1, StartTime)
             ),
        BookedMinutes ( [Date], [Time], [BranchID], BookingCount )
          AS ( SELECT   [Date] ,
                        [Time] ,
                        [BranchID] ,
                        BookingCount
               FROM     BookedMinutesByRole
               UNION
               SELECT   [Date] ,
                        [Time] ,
                        [BranchID] ,
                        BookingCount
               FROM     BookedMinutesByWhiteList
             ),
        PreRender ( [Date], [Time], [BranchID], [BookingCount] )
          AS ( SELECT   OpenDatesAndMinutes.[Date] ,
                        OpenDatesAndMinutes.[Time] ,
                        OpenDatesAndMinutes.[BranchID] ,
                        ISNULL(BookedMinutes.BookingCount, 0) AS BookingCount
               FROM     OpenDatesAndMinutes
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN BookedMinutes ON OpenDatesAndMinutes.BranchID = BookedMinutes.BranchID
                                                         AND OpenDatesAndMinutes.[Date] = BookedMinutes.[Date]
                                                         AND OpenDatesAndMinutes.[Time] = BookedMinutes.[Time]
             ),
        CrossTabPrep ( [Date], [Time], [BranchID], [BookingCount], [Grp] )
          AS ( SELECT   [Date] ,
                        [Time] ,
                        [BranchID] ,
                        [BookingCount] ,
                        DATEPART(HOUR, Time) * 60 + DATEPART(MINUTE, Time) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [BranchID], Date, [BookingCount] ORDER BY Time ) AS [Grp]
               FROM     PreRender
             ),
        DeletedBranches ( [BranchID] )
          AS ( SELECT   [ShopNo]
               FROM     [dbo].[vw_BranchList]
               WHERE    [Branch_Deleted] = 1
             ),
        FinalRender ( [BranchID], [Date], [Start Time], [End Time], [Duration], [EntryCount], [EntryColour] )
          AS ( SELECT   [BranchID] ,
                        [Date] ,
                        MIN([Time]) AS [Start Time] ,
                        MAX([Time]) AS [End Time] ,
                        ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN([Time]), MAX([Time])), 0) AS Duration ,
                        --dbo.format_timeV2(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN([Time]), MAX([Time])), 0)) AS DurationF ,
                        [BookingCount] AS EntryCount ,
                        CASE WHEN [BookingCount] = 0 THEN 'Red'
                             WHEN [BookingCount] = 1 THEN 'Green'
                             ELSE 'Yellow'
                        END AS EntryColour
               FROM     CrossTabPrep
               GROUP BY [BranchID] ,
                        [Date] ,
                        [BookingCount] ,
                        [Grp]
             )
            SELECT  [BranchID] ,
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 7, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(day, -1 - ( DATEPART(dw, [Date]) + @@DATEFIRST - 2 ) % 7, [Date]), 103) + ' 23:59:59', 103)), 103) AS WeekEnding ,
                    [Date] ,
                    [Start Time] ,
                    [End Time] ,
                    [Duration] ,
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( [Duration] * 60 ) / 3600) + 'h ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROUND(( ( CONVERT(FLOAT, ( ( [Duration] * 60 ) % 3600 )) ) / 3600 ) * 60, 0)) + 'm' AS [DurationF] ,
                    [EntryCount] ,
                    [EntryColour] ,
                    CASE WHEN [EntryCount] = 0 THEN 'Red'
                         WHEN [EntryCount] >= 1 THEN 'Green'
                    END AS DurationColour ,
                    CASE WHEN [EntryCount] = 0 THEN 'This period of open-time isnt covered'
                         WHEN [EntryCount] >= 1 THEN 'This period of open-time is covered by ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [EntryCount]) + ' booking(s)'
                    END AS [DurationComment]
            FROM    FinalRender
            WHERE   FinalRender.BranchID NOT IN ( SELECT    [BranchID]
                                                  FROM      DeletedBranches )
```

Comment: Inline comments in the code would be helpful.

Comment: So unclear.  You have two CTEs but do not show the query where you use them.  Refer to joining Branch but there is not table named branch.

Comment: @Blam i didnt see how the rest of the CTE (which is extensive) would help solve the problem of joining 13,000,000 rows? but either way i've edited my question to include the full CTE.

Comment: Materialize is writing to a table.  Permanent or temp.  A CTE is just syntax and you have no real control over how many times it is evaluated. (OK there are some tricks to play with CTE).  With a temp table you can force it to be evaluated once and more important create an index.

Comment: And don't wait to the end to exclude DeleteBranches.  Do that as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's funny, because you have answered your own question with your questions at the end. You should just try them all but to summarize:

1. Materialize CTEs for better performance. You never know when SQL Server will evaluate a CTE more than once
2. You can build indexex against temporary tables.
3. I'm not sure how you jumped from `[DayOfWeek],DATEADD(MINUTE, N - 1, StartTime)` to the join on `[Date],[Time]` on the other, but having two columns here doesn't make sense. Use either a single `datetime` or a bigint representing the `seconds` from an epoch. UnixTimestamp works well here.

Comment: Can you just confirm what you mean by Materialize?

Comment: Most probably he means to store result of CTE in permanent tables and index them, instead of relying on memory.

Comment: Materialize = create a temporary table.  You can index a temp table, but not a CTE.

Comment: Looks like splitting the CTE into 2 inserts to populate two indexed temp tables and then joining those is definitely the way to go - looks like i'll have my hands full tomorrow, cheers for the answer

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is not based on your data, but on generated test data, so it can be not fully applicable.

Proposal: In order to move from quadratic degradation of performance to at least linear, batch processing can be used, if data is distributed equally among batch periods.

In example below 2 years of bookings is being processed with 3 day batch interval and it takes it 2 minutes and 30 seconds to get back free periods per day per branch.

Test run results:

```
2 years - 2 minutes and 30 seconds 
4 years - 4 minutes and 55 seconds.
6 years - 6 minutes and 41 seconds
```

It incorporates the same logic that is being used in question by using numbers to find non-matching minutes.

Schema and test data creation:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('vwRandomNumber') IS NOT NULL
        DROP VIEW vwRandomNumber
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.fnRandNumber') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION  dbo.fnRandNumber
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.fnRandomInt') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.fnRandomInt
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('tblNumbers') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.tblNumbers
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('Branches') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Branches
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('OpeningHours') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE OpeningHours
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('Bookings') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Bookings
    GO

    CREATE VIEW vwRandomNumber
    AS
    SELECT Rand() RandomNumber;
    GO

    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnRandNumber()
    RETURNS FLOAT
    AS
    BEGIN
      RETURN (SELECT TOP 1 RandomNumber FROM vwRandomNumber)
    END;
    GO

    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnRandomInt(@FromNumber INT, @ToNumber INT)
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN
      RETURN (@FromNumber + ROUND(dbo.fnRandNumber()*(@ToNumber - @FromNumber),0))
    END;
    GO

    CREATE TABLE tblNumbers 
    (
       NumberID INT PRIMARY KEY 
    )

    CREATE TABLE Branches
    (
       BranchID INT
      ,BranchName NVARCHAR(100)
    );
    GO

    ;WITH cteNumbers AS (
      SELECT 1 N 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT N+1 FROM cteNumbers WHERE N<100
    )
    INSERT INTO
        Branches
    SELECT N, CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(100)) FROM cteNumbers
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)

    CREATE TABLE OpeningHours
    (
        BranchID INT 
      , Date DATETIME
      , OpenFrom DATETIME
      , OpenTo DATETIME 
    );
    GO

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_OpeningHours
    ON OpeningHours ([Date], [BranchID])

    GO

    CREATE TABLE Bookings
    (
         BranchID INT
       , BookingDate DATETIME
       , BookingFrom DATETIME
       , BookingTo DATETIME  
    )

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_Bookings
    ON Bookings ([BookingDate],[BranchID])

    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = DATEADD(month,0,DATEADD(D,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())))

    ;WITH cteNumbers AS (
      SELECT 1 N 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT N+1 FROM cteNumbers WHERE N<2000
    )
    INSERT INTO
      OpeningHours
      (
          BranchID
        , Date
        , OpenFrom
        , OpenTo
      )
    SELECT
      Branches.BranchID
    , Dates.Day
    , DATEADD(hour,7,Dates.Day)
    , DATEADD(hour,19,Dates.Day)
    FROM
      (
        SELECT 
          DATEADD(d,N,@StartDate) Day
        FROM
          cteNumbers
      ) Dates
    CROSS JOIN
      Branches
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);

    INSERT INTO Bookings
    SELECT 
       OpeningHours.BranchID
      ,OpeningHours.Date
      ,BookingHours.StartDate
      ,BookingHours.ToDate
    FROM
      OpeningHours
    CROSS APPLY
      (
         SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(0,3), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(4,9), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) ToDate UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(1,5), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(6,9), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(2,5), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(5,8), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) TODate UNION ALL
          SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(0,3), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(4,9), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) ToDate UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(1,5), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(6,9), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(2,5), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(5,8), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) TODate UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(0,3), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(4,9), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) ToDate UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(1,5), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(6,9), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(2,5), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(5,8), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) TODate UNION ALL
          SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(0,3), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(4,9), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) ToDate UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(1,5), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(6,9), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(2,5), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) StartDate
                ,DATEADD(hour, dbo.fnRandomInt(5,8), OpeningHours.OpenFrom) TODate 
      ) BookingHours;

    ;WITH cteNumbers AS (
      SELECT 1 N 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT N+1 FROM cteNumbers WHERE N<5000
    )
    INSERT INTO
        tblNumbers
    SELECT N FROM cteNumbers
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)

    --SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bookings WHERE
```

Scripts to get periods with no bookings:

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF OBJECT_ID('tblBranchFreePeriods') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE tblBranchFreePeriods

    IF OBJECT_ID('tblFreeMinutes') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE tblFreeMinutes

    CREATE TABLE tblBranchFreePeriods
    (
          BranchID INT
        , Date DATETIME
        , PeriodStartDate DATETIME
        , PeriodEndDate DATETIME
    )

    CREATE TABLE tblFreeMinutes 
    (
         BranchID INT 
        ,Date DATETIME
        ,FreeMinute INT
    )

    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tblStartDates') IS NOT NULL
                DROP TABLE tblStartDates

    CREATE TABLE tblStartDates
    (
          BranchID INT
        , Date DATETIME 
        , PeriodStartDate DATETIME
    )

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_tblStartDates
        ON tblStartDates([BranchID],[Date])

    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tblEndDates') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE tblEndDates

    CREATE TABLE tblEndDates
    (
          BranchID INT
        , Date DATETIME 
        , PeriodEndDate DATETIME
    )

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_tblEndDate
        ON tblEndDates ([BranchID],[Date])


    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_tblFreeMinutes
        ON tblFreeMinutes ([BranchID],[Date],FreeMinute)

    DECLARE @ProcessFromDate DATETIME, @ProcessTo DATETIME
    SELECT @ProcessFromDate = MIN(OpenFrom), @ProcessTo = DATEADD(year,2,@ProcessFromDate) FROM OpeningHours 

    DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 3

    DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME = GETDATE()

    WHILE (@ProcessFromDate <= @ProcessTo) BEGIN

            TRUNCATE TABLE tblFreeMinutes
            TRUNCATE TABLE tblStartDates
            TRUNCATE TABLE tblEndDates

            SET @StartTime = GETDATE()              

            DECLARE @DateFrom DATETIME = @ProcessFromDate, @DateTo DATETIME = DATEADD(d,@BatchSize,@ProcessFromDate)

            PRINT 'Date From ' + CAST(@DateFrom AS NVARCHAR(50))
            PRINT 'Date To ' + CAST(@DateTO AS NVARCHAR(50))

            INSERT INTO
                tblFreeMinutes
            SELECT
                OpeningHours.BranchID
               ,OpeningHours.Date
               ,tblOpeningHourMinutes.NumberID Minute   
            FROM
                OpeningHours
            INNER JOIN
              tblNumbers tblOpeningHourMinutes
            ON
                NumberID 
                    BETWEEN DATEDIFF(minute,OpeningHours.Date,OpeningHours.OpenFrom)
                AND
                    DATEDIFF(minute,OpeningHours.Date,OpeningHours.OpenTo)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
               Bookings
            ON
                    Bookings.BookingDate = OpeningHours.Date   
                AND
                    Bookings.BranchID = OpeningHours.BranchID 
                AND
                    tblOpeningHourMinutes.NumberID
               BETWEEN
                   DATEDIFF(minute,Bookings.BookingDate,Bookings.BookingFrom)
               AND
                   DATEDIFF(minute,Bookings.BookingDAte,Bookings.BookingTo)              
            WHERE
               OpeningHours.Date BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
            AND
               Bookings.BookingDate IS NULL
            OPTION ( FORCE ORDER )

            PRINT 'Populate free minutes ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond,@StartTime,GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(50))
            SET @StartTime = GETDATE()


            INSERT INTO
                tblStartDates
            SELECT 
                  tblFreeMinutes.BranchID
                , tblFreeMinutes.Date
                , DATEADD(minute,tblFreeMInutes.FreeMinute,tblFreeMinutes.Date)
            FROM
                tblFreeMinutes
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                tblFreeMinutes tblFreeMinutesIn  
            ON
                tblFreeMinutesIn.Date = tblFreeMinutes.Date
            AND
                tblFreeMinutesIn.BranchID = tblFreeMinutes.BranchID
            AND
                tblFreeMinutesIn.FreeMinute = tblFreeMinutes.FreeMinute-1
            WHERE
                tblFreeMinutesIn.BranchID IS NULL

            PRINT 'Populate start dates ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond,@StartTime,GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(50))
            SET @StartTime = GETDATE()

            INSERT INTO
                tblEndDates
            SELECT 
                  tblFreeMinutes.BranchID
                , tblFreeMinutes.Date
                , DATEADD(minute,tblFreeMInutes.FreeMinute,tblFreeMinutes.Date)
            FROM
                tblFreeMinutes
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                tblFreeMinutes tblFreeMinutesIn  
            ON
                tblFreeMinutesIn.Date = tblFreeMinutes.Date
            AND
                tblFreeMinutesIn.BranchID = tblFreeMinutes.BranchID
            AND
                tblFreeMinutesIn.FreeMinute = tblFreeMinutes.FreeMinute+1
            WHERE
                tblFreeMinutesIn.BranchID IS NULL

            PRINT 'Populate end dates ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond,@StartTime,GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(50))
            SET @StartTime = GETDATE()

            INSERT INTO
                tblBranchFreePeriods
            SELECT 
                  tblStartDates.BranchID
                , tblStartDates.Date
                , tblStartDates.PeriodStartDate
                , tblEndDate.PeriodEndDate 
            FROM 
                tblStartDates 
            CROSS APPLY
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 
                        *
                    FROM
                        tblEndDates
                    WHERE
                        tblEndDates.BranchID = tblStartDates.BranchID
                    AND
                        tblEndDates.Date = tblStartDates.Date
                    AND
                        tblEndDates.PeriodEndDate > tblStartDates.PeriodStartDate
                    ORDER BY
                        PeriodEndDate ASC
                ) tblEndDate

            PRINT 'Return intervals ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond,@StartTime,GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(50))
            SET @StartTime = GETDATE()

            SET @ProcessFromDate = DATEADD(d,@BatchSize+1,@ProcessFromDate)

            PRINT ''
            PRINT ''

            RAISERROR ('',0,0) WITH NOWAIT

            --SELECT * FROM tblBranchFreePeriods

           --BREAK      
    END

    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        tblBranchFreePeriods
    ORDER BY
        1,2,3
```